# React Icon Changes on Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-icons

I cant for the life of me figure this out.  I would like the React icons below to fill and stay filled on click and change back to outlined when another is clicked.  Here is the code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { AiOutlineHome } from "react-icons/ai";
import { AiFillHome } from "react-icons/ai";
import { BsCalendarCheck } from "react-icons/bs";
import { BsCalendarCheckFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { BsCalendarPlusFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { BsCalendarPlus } from "react-icons/bs";
import "./FooterNav.css";

const FooterNav = () => {
  return (
    <div className="footer-nav-container">
      <div className="footer-nav-icon">
        <Link to="/">
          <AiOutlineHome className="home-icon" />
          <p>Home</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="footer-nav-icon">
        <Link to="/past">
          <BsCalendarCheck className="calendar-check-icon" />
          <p>Past</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="footer-nav-icon">
        <Link to="/upcoming">
          <BsCalendarPlus className="calendar-plus-icon" />
          <p>Upcoming</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FooterNav;
```

I would love some assistance with this.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean when you are on home page, home icon will be filled, others will be outlined. When you visit Past calender will be filled and others outline?

Comment: @CodeThing Yes exactly!!

Comment: You can make use of useLocation hook from react-router-dom. This give you current location details. Based on that you can decide which icon to load. Reference: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments,

You can make use of useLocation hook from react-router-dom. This give you current location details. Based on that you can decide which icon to load.

I haven't tested this but something like this would work

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { AiOutlineHome } from "react-icons/ai";
import { AiFillHome } from "react-icons/ai";
import { BsCalendarCheck } from "react-icons/bs";
import { BsCalendarCheckFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { BsCalendarPlusFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { BsCalendarPlus } from "react-icons/bs";
import "./FooterNav.css";

const FooterNav = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);

  return (
    <div className="footer-nav-container">
      <div className="footer-nav-icon">
        <Link to="/">
          {location.pathname === "/" ? <AiFillHome className="home-icon" /> : <AiOutlineHome className="home-icon" />}
          <p>Home</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="footer-nav-icon">
        <Link to="/past">
          {location.pathname === "/past" ? <BsCalendarCheckFill className="calendar-check-icon" /> : <BsCalendarCheck className="calendar-check-icon" />}
          <p>Past</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="footer-nav-icon">
        <Link to="/upcoming">
          {location.pathname === "/upcoming" ? <BsCalendarPlusFill className="calendar-plus-icon" /> : <BsCalendarPlus className="calendar-plus-icon" /> }
          <p>Upcoming</p>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FooterNav;
```

Comment: Amazing!! You rock!!  Thank you!!!

Comment: how would you keep the icon in the active state (filled) when traveling to other pages within that tab?

Comment: Nevermind...I just use || and the route and it'll stay filled

Answer (score 0):

`useLocation` hook from [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location) is good a start. Try something along the ways:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AiOutlineHome } from "react-icons/ai";
import { AiFillHome } from "react-icons/ai";
    
const FooterNav = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const isLocationHome = location.pathname === '/'

  return (
    <div className="footer-nav-container">
      <div className="footer-nav-icon">
        <Link to="/">
          {isLocationHome ? 
            <AiFillHome /> :
            <AiOutlineHome className="home-icon" />  
          }
          <p>Home</p>
        </Link>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can use the `useLocation()` hook as shown in this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-lehmann-qfm6uf?file=/src/styles.css